# Cannot index UVs by [0]/[1] or .x/.y (broken coordinates in python!)

Tags: python, scripting, uv

Trying to get the XY of a `uv_layer[index].uv` by using [0] and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZgmc.png), or .x and .y, return extremely weird results. However using the uv value itself (e.g. `print(uv_layer[index].uv)`) gives correct results. Example:

[image]

This is not just a printing issue. When writing the values to a file, I get these same broken values in the file. Seems only that 0.0/0.0001 coords are broken maybe?

How do I obtain the correct X and Y values, individually?

Answer (score 1):

That's not specifically a blender issue, it is showing the [inaccuracy of representing a decimal number in binary storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples). The python docs have [a page](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) explaining the issue and show some ways around it, the best is probably using [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatspec) which replaces the older `'%.3g' % val` style.

```
>>> val = 0.1 + 0.2
>>> print(val)
0.30000000000000004
>>> print('{:.3g}'.format(val)) # '.3g' will give 3 significant digits
0.3
```

While python has the [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html) to better support decimal numbers, it doesn't help when working with blender's data.