# Changing amount of decimal digits in dimensions, without source code?

Tags: python

I had a short, but quick question. I was posting this as a bug by going to "Report a Bug" within Blender. It's version 2.79. But when something exceeds 100m or 100', it won't show any decimal digits at all.

So, I was wondering, is it possible to get the decimals back by simply using the Python Console within Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set blender to show units, it doesn't display zero only fractional values. Values that have a fractional component will display as you expect.

[image: object transforms]

You can get the values via python, see the [object api reference](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html) for property names.

```
>>> bpy.context.object.location
Vector((1.2345000505447388, 0.0, 0.0))

>>> bpy.context.object.dimensions
Vector((100.12300109863281, 2.0, 2.0))
```

As you can see, you also get [floating point binary storage issues](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78459/935).

Comment: That's a good solution. Actually, it was just what I was looking for. I know 3ds Max had this feature, in Maxscript, so I thought Python must be having something similar. But I found out that, by reporting this issue, they will be reverting back to more decimal digits. Say, 102m will be 102.06m again.

Comment: Also, what version of Blender did you use in that screenshot?

Comment: A daily build from a few weeks ago. Just looking through versions, 2.77 shows more places, 2.79 shows less. Seems it is something that keeps getting messed with.